# WCF service - async iimplementation

Tags: performance, wcf, asynchronous, scalability, async-await

In a standalone windows application (Wpf/Winforms) I can see the benefits of using async implementation of long running methods to keep the UI responsive.

As I know, the IIS is will take care of the threading stuff e.g the web service will not block while its processing another request.

So my questions are:

1. When it comes to implementing a web service using async/await, does that makes sence ?
2. Will we gain any performance/scaling benefits for making the implementation async e.g using the async/await keywords.
3. To make a wcf service scale and perform well, can the only tuning be done in the config file or are there other things to think of ?

I'm interested in hearing your experiences and not only links to theoretical articles.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web services in general can gain a benefit from `async`/`await` **if** they use naturally-asynchronous operations. This is because `async` can return the IIS thread to the thread pool while it is waiting for the operation to complete, instead of blocking that thread.

I haven't heard many numbers on WCF services, but on the MVC/WebAPI side I've heard of scalability benefits in the 10x-100x range.

"Naturally-asynchronous" usually means "I/O-based". Obviously, there's no benefit if you just use `Task.Run` to offload a CPU-bound (or blocking) call onto a thread pool thread - you'd just be trading one thread for another. But if your implementation is I/O-bound, then you can use `async` to make maximum use of the thread pool.

Another thing to keep in mind is the scalability of the system as a whole. I.e., if your WCF calls all just turn around and call a single SQL Server backend, then you probably won't get any benefit from scaling WCF because the SQL Server will be your scalability bottleneck.

But in general, I recommend using `async`/`await` on your server-side code for any naturally-asynchronous work.

Comment: I like your wording with "naturally-asynchronous". Will start to use that.